# Show a project navigator for a small project in IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.3

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.3 community edition.

I noticed that IntelliJ uses some smart algorithms  for the layout for the user interface.

When I open a larger project it will display a type of project navigator on the left.

When I open a smaller project consisting of only a few Maven modules it will not display this project navigator.

How can I show the project navigator? Can IntelliJ be configured in such a way that the navigator is always shown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have the Project tool window open (via `View > Tool Windows > Project`) you can select *what* that tool window displays by clicking on the drop down in the top left hand corner. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

The pre canned views selectable in that drop down control *how* and *what*  IntelliJ displays. From the [docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/project-tool-window.html):

> **Project view**. In this view, all the project items along with their dependencies (SDKs and libraries) are shown. The emphasis is on the directory structure (though the packages are also shown).
>
> **Packages view**. The emphasis is on the package structure of the project. The modules, SDKs and libraries, by default, are not shown.

Nothing new here so far, I suspect, but that's just setting the scene.

IntelliJ does not derive the view status of the Project tool window, instead it just displays (or does not display) this tool window based on whether it was displayed when that project was last used. So, for your project in which the Project tool window is not displayed; just display it (`View > Tool Windows > Project`) and as long as it is still visible when you close that project it will be made visible, by default, the next time you open that project.